# How to do addition on a specific column?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Sorry if related question is asked before but I could not find a solution of it. Actually I am retrieving data from `SQLite` and doing addition on "count" column on every user input add the current plus previous input. Everything is working fine. I am trying to show that retrieved count from database in a `Textview` of a `listview`. When I do SUM(count) `FROM TABLE_NAME`, I can see the count but the problem is `listview` is showing only one item in list. It just changing the first item or overwriting. How can I solve this problem. Please help. Showing code snippets below :

This is public function from where I am retrieving data from `SQLite`.

```
 public List<Product> getAllProduct() {
    List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(count) From shirts ORDER BY id DESC  ", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        int id = cursor.getInt(0);
        String title = cursor.getString(1);
        String price = cursor.getString(2);
        String quantity = cursor.getString(3);
        int count = cursor.getInt(4);

        products.add(new Product(id, title, price, quantity, count));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return products;
}
```

Comment: `SELECT SUM(count) From shirts ORDER BY id DESC  ` only return number of item in table.not the list.

Comment: @OmInfowaveDevelopers Can you please tell me how can I achieve that specific implementation. I want to return list with column previous + current value in a textview.

Comment: please explain in details what you want?want to add new item after that retrieve update list?explain in details

Comment: @OmInfowaveDevelopers Take it as a Shopping Cart. When user add new item in cart, the cart gets updated with the number of items user choose. I want to achieve the same but within listview item.

Comment: use "SELECT * From shirts ORDER BY id DESC"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@OmInfowareDevelopers This is the answer I wanted to implement. You did not put cursor value in the int variable that's why it is always returning null. Well I really appreciate you time and leading to me an exact answer I wanted.

```
public int getTotalItem() {
    int totalItem = 0;
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(count) From shirts ORDER BY id DESC  ", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        totalItem = cursor.getInt(0);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return totalItem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use two different query for that

1)Return list of all product

```
public List<Product> getAllProduct() {
    List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * From shirts ORDER BY id DESC  ", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        int id = cursor.getInt(0);
        String title = cursor.getString(1);
        String price = cursor.getString(2);
        String quantity = cursor.getString(3);
        int count = cursor.getInt(4);

        products.add(new Product(id, title, price, quantity, count));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return products;
}
```

2)Item count in cart

```
public int getTotalItem() {
    int totalItem=0;
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT count(*) as totalItem  From shirts ORDER BY id DESC  ", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        int id = cursor.getInt(0);
         cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return totalItem;
}
```

Comment: @OmInfowareDevelopers Great ... it works with some more implementation. Thanks, really saved my hours.